# Moving an element from a "stack" to a new line for small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what I want to achieve in Bootstrap:

[image]

The first one I can achieve by defining B and C under the common div.
The second one I can achieve by defining C separately on the new row.
I don't know how to get both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it possible with just bootstrap, since it use flex-layout base class, and it can't do what you want (correct me if i'm wrong though, i haven't touch bootstrap much since v4 come out).

So what i'm suggest here is a custom grid-layout base class to the parent div of all 3 childs, which you can use with media query to custom layout the way you want. All other bootstrap classes can still use as normal otherwise. Basically i create a table like area with pre-defined sections, then i 'attach' the childs to their desire location.

*HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row grid">
        <div class="col_a col-6 col-md-12">Col A</div>
        <div class="col_b col-6 col-md-12">Col B</div>
        <div class="col_c col-12">Col C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS

```
.col_a {
    background: red;
}
.col_b {
    background: yellow;
}
.col_c {
    background: green;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: "left right-top" "left right-bottom";
    }
    .col_a {
        grid-area: left;
    }
    .col_b {
        grid-area: right-top;
    }
    .col_c {
        grid-area: right-bottom;
    }
}
```

[Demo - resize screen to see the effect](https://jsfiddle.net/pdtvkrzf/).